# CLOC not counting actionscript files correctly

Tags: count

When I used [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) on an Actionscript project folder there seems to be something wrong with the line count. For the project I'd expect something like a couple of thousand lines of code, but I get this:

```
      27 text files.
      27 unique files.                              
Using temp dir [/var/folders/Iv/IvtpxxljEvmq44ihKLV3UU+++TI/-Tmp-/I2_EYvn0vb] \
 to install Regexp::Common
       1 file ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.56  T=0.5 s (52.0 files/s, 296.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ActionScript                    26             38             26             84
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            26             38             26             84
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I browsed to the folder of a downloaded Actionscript 3D library and did the same command there and it seems to count just fine.

Also the tool seems to count my PHP or JavaScript just fine, but just not the Actionscript.

I played around with different options, but can't seem to figure out why it is not counting properly. From the looks of it, it counts one comment per file (the file count and the counted file names are OK), which makes me wonder if there is something wrong with the way comments are detected, or line breaks. (Mac OS X here, the files are all in unicode.)

Anyone got an idea?

---

I also made a single file to just test the counting and for this alone it works fine:

```
/**
 * a description
 */
package com.foo.bar {

    public class Foobar {

        // really no, this is a comment
        private var lorem:String = "ipsum";

        /**
         * OMG, it's a constructor
         */
        public function Foobar() {

        }

        private function ladida():Boolean {
            // yes, genius
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

With CLOC tracing to the console:

```
http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.56  T=0.5 s (2.0 files/s, 50.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ActionScript                     1              7              8             10
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: From the page docs on [limitations](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/#Limitations): "Identifying comments within source code is trickier than one might expect. Many languages would need a complete parser to be counted correctly. cloc does not attempt to parse any of the languages it aims to count and therefore is an imperfect tool." -- You may have found bug in this limitation.

Comment: @MichaelT I updated the question with the example of a simple class file I just wrote to test, and counting for that file alone works like a charm. Also, counting the other project source folders works fine.

Comment: You might want to visit http://sourceforge.net/p/cloc/bugs/ - the specifics of the bug tracking and the support forums there may provide you with more information and are more likely to be monitored by the people who are capable of identifying and fixing this bug (I hesitate to call it a bug, it might just be some poorly documented errant behavior) or working around it.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing the CLOC results for single files instead of whole directories, I noticed that some files would count just fine, while others would get counted as one-liners.

Upon trying around, I figured that the files that have a wrong line count had line endings set to `Mac OS 9` - setting line endings to `Unix` or `Windows` in my editor fixes the problem alltogether and the counts are right.

It beats me why my editor would default to `Max OS 9` line endings, and why it does so only for a certain file type (.as files), but that seems to have been the cause.

Probably the count for the whole project gets nullified if only one file can not be counted right due to those wrong line endings.